# File not loading properly in C

Tags: c, string, compare

I'm trying to compare a string using a pointer to the array and the destination as defined.

```c
string destination;

int flightcompare(Flights FDA[], String destination)
{
    int j=0;
    Flights founddestination[10];
    for (int i=0;i<MAXARRAYSIZE;i++)
    {
        (strcmp(Flight *FDA[i]->destination,destination)==0);
        founddestination[j]= FDA[i];
        j++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your `strcmp` line doesn't make any sense, cause you're not checking the boolean value which is the result of your comparison.
In general, it should be put in an `if` statement.

There's another problem though since there's no need to compare string objects with `strcmp`.
You can just compare them with operator `==`.

```
if (FDA[i].destination == destination) {
    // they're equal -> do something
} else {
    // they're not equal -> do something else
}
```

That's assuming `Flights` type has a 'destination' public member.

---

Moreover, why put them in the `founddestination` array if you're not using it? and what is the purpose of returning an int?

If you want to know if there's **any** mismatching destination you can return a boolean.
If you want to return the number of equal destinations / non equal destinations you can just count them in an int.

Assuming you aim for the boolean solution i'd write:

```
bool flightcompare(Flights FDA[], String destination) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXARRAYSIZE; ++i) {
        if (FDA[i].destination != destination) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you want to return the amount of matching flights i'd write:

```
int flightcompare(Flights FDA[], String destination) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXARRAYSIZE; ++i) {
        if (FDA[i].destination == destination) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the programming language but I am assuming it is one with `string`as a data type.

In your code, there's a Semicolon at the end of

```
strcmp(Flight *FDA[i]->destination,destination)==0);
```

which makes use of `strcmp`redundant.
Remove that Semicolon.
Plus You don't need to pass `Flight*`to `strcmp`
So, With these modifications, Function should look like:

```
int flightcompare(Flights FDA[], String destination)
{
        int j=0;
        Flights founddestination[10];
        for (int i=0;i<MAXARRAYSIZE;i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(FDA[i]->destination,destination)==0)
            {
                founddestination[j]= FDA[i];
                j++;
                if(j >= 10)
                {
                   break; // Stop Looping as Array is full
                }
            }
        }
    return j; // Return Count of the Flights found.
}
```